# Python on gae datetime to UTC format

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, timeago

I have a datetime on my model

```
2013-02-19 05:29:27.874648
```

I am using jquery timeago.. but the problem is it don't give the desire output..

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="{{ activity.created }}">{{ activity.date }}</time>
```

the code above is my sample html code..

here's my javascript :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
    });
</script>
```

my question is.. should I convert it to UTC format??.. If that so! how do I convert it?.. convert it in python way or javascript??.. how do I do it?.

Comment: what is your desire output ?

Comment: It should be a minute ago or an hour ago.. It depends on my timezone

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question then .

How can I convert in UTC

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

date_str = "2009-05-05 22:28:15"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime_obj_utc = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
print datetime_obj_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z")
```

You need to install `pytz`

If you want to add some timestamp in your current time   .

Do something like this

```
future = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
return time.mktime(future.timetuple()).
```

Please go through this article [time.mktime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime)

Comment: Is there another way without installing pytz?.. ahm.. can I do convertion in javascript??..

Answer (score 0):

You generally want the date to already be in UTC (or explicitly offset from UTC) on the server, then converted at the last second (pun intended) to the client's local timezone.

With jquery-timeago, assuming the date is already (relative to) UTC, you can format it as such (in Python, server-side) and jquery-timeago should figure out the rest correctly.

Here's what I use to format UTC dates in my own HTML templates:

```
{{ activity.date.isoformat() + 'Z' }}
```

Comment: the code above given me an arror 'str object' has no attribute 'isoformat'

Comment: @Leonard: That means that `activity.date` is a string (`str` object) and not a `datetime.datetime` object. That means the date was already formatted before it got to the view! You'll need to find out where that's happening and format it properly there (or even better, leave it as a `datetime` object so the view can choose how to render it!).